# Russian dashes with polyglossia

Tags: punctuation, typography, polyglossia

In russian typography the dashes are recommended to be typeset as `"---`, not as `~---`, and `"--~` as a dash between surnames, according to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Cyrillic_script. The examples shown are using `babel`, but I use `polyglossia` and the result is wrong:

[image]

How can I use these `babel` way of typesetting without switching from `polyglossia`?

Here is a MWE (I use LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Georgia}

\begin{document}

    А"--- Б.

    Ньютон"--~Лейбниц.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can activate the shorthands with the option babelshorthands (by language or globally, see the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Georgia}

\begin{document}

    А"--- Б.

    Ньютон"--~Лейбниц.

\end{document}
```

[image]